# Javascript: Why does this code just iterate until the array's last value right away?

Tags: javascript, arrays

this code is actually supposed to change the color each time when you press the button by changing it's class.
But unfortunately it just falls through until the last value of the array and I don't quite understand why it would do so. The button ends up being purple. Hope you have an idea.

HTML and CSS should be fine.

Thank you!

Code:

```js
function changeClass() {
  var classVariations = ["red", "blue", "yellow,", "pink", "purple"];
  for (var i = 0; i < classVariations.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById("differentColors").classList.add(classVariations[i]);
  }
}

function changeColor() {
  document.getElementById("differentColors").addEventListener("click", changeClass);
  document.getElementById("differentColors").classList.remove(classVariations[i]);
}

window.addEventListener("load", changeColor);
```

```css
.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.pink {
  background-color: pink;
}

.purple {
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<button id="differentColors">Change my color.</button>
```

Comment: Formatting your code would be helpful.

Comment: How are you accessing `i` in your `changeColor` function when it's declared in `changeClass`?

Comment: @CharlieFish I know it doesn't look pretty that way. Couldn't help it, the website just wouldn't process it right.

Comment: @Nat_ Next time take the little bit of time to put it from a prettifier before posting.

Comment: @CharlieFish I really appreciate the help people give me at stackoverflow and I definitly don't wanna bother anybody with ugly code. Thank you very much for telling me about the prettifier, I didn't even know something like this would exist!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    var classVariations = ["red", "blue", "yellow", "pink", "purple"];
    var count = 0;

    function changeClass() {
        document.getElementById("differentColors").className = classVariations[count];
        count = count < classVariations.length ? count + 1 : 0;
    } 

    function changeColor() {
        document.getElementById("differentColors").addEventListener("click", changeClass);
    }

    window.addEventListener("load", changeColor);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is because that it's running through each color and setting the color to the last array element. So it basically instantly changes the color to all the array elements, faster than you can notice.

Changing your JavaScript to the following should work.

```
var currentColorIndex = 0;
var classVariations = ["red", "blue", "yellow", "pink", "purple"];
function changeClass() {
  document.getElementById("differentColors").classList.remove(classVariations[currentColorIndex]); // remove current color
  if (currentColorIndex != classVariations.length - 1) {
    currentColorIndex++; // increase current color index
  } else {
    currentColorIndex = 0; // reset current color index to 0 since it's the end of the array
  }
  document.getElementById("differentColors").classList.add(classVariations[currentColorIndex]); // set new color
}

function changeColor() {
  document.getElementById("differentColors").addEventListener("click", changeClass);
  document.getElementById("differentColors").classList.add(classVariations[currentColorIndex]); // set first color to first color in array
}

window.addEventListener("load", changeColor);
```

Basically storing the current color and incrementing it by 1 every time you click should work.

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems with variable scope. And you are looping though all the colors in an instant. Off the top of my head, this is how I would do it:

```
var classVariations = ["red", "blue", "yellow", "pink", "purple"];
var i = 0;

var $myBtn = document.getElementById("differentColors")

function changeClass() {
  let iNew = i < classVariations.length-1 ? i + 1 : 0;
  $myBtn.classList.remove(classVariations[i]);
  $myBtn.classList.add(classVariations[iNew]);
  i = iNew;
}

function changeColor() {
  $myBtn.addEventListener("click", changeClass);
}

window.addEventListener("load", changeColor);
```

I also cached the DOM selector because that is good practice. Also fixed a typo - a spurious comma in the yellow color string.